# npm install error node

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, react-native

```
D:\react_space\Demo_1>npm install

> bufferutil@1.2.1 install D:\react_space\Demo_1\node_modules\bufferutil
> node-gyp rebuild


D:\react_space\Demo_1\node_modules\bufferutil>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: read ECONNRESET
gyp ERR! stack     at exports._errnoException (util.js:856:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at TLSWrap.onread (net.js:546:26)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10240
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\react_space\Demo_1\node_modules\bufferutil
gyp ERR! node -v v5.6.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.2.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN install:bufferutil@1.2.1 bufferutil@1.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN install:bufferutil@1.2.1 Exit status 1

> utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install D:\react_space\Demo_1\node_modules\utf-8-validate
> node-gyp rebuild


D:\react_space\Demo_1\node_modules\utf-8-validate>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "" rebuild )
gyp WARN install got an error, rolling back install
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 104.20.22.46:443
gyp ERR! stack     at Object.exports._errnoException (util.js:856:11)
gyp ERR! stack     at exports._exceptionWithHostPort (util.js:879:20)
gyp ERR! stack     at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1053:14)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.10240
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd D:\react_space\Demo_1\node_modules\utf-8-validate
gyp ERR! node -v v5.6.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.2.1
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN install:utf-8-validate@1.2.1 utf-8-validate@1.2.1 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN install:utf-8-validate@1.2.1 Exit status 1
npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.0.8
```

Development Environment

```
win10 64
node 5.6.0
npm 3.6.0
```

---

When I perform npm install command error message...The dependencies of package.json ss already installed.

执行npm install的时候出现的错误，然后package.json里面配置的第三方依赖也已经安装到node_modules 文件夹中

Somebody in the same problem with me?!

Answer (score 1):

If you do not have a package.json file in your directory, do `npm init`

You need to specify which package you would like to install. `npm install <package-name>`

Comment: Here has been a package.json file.When I execute npm install <package-name> command happen the same mistake.I think the error occurred in nodejs ,but i can't find it.

Comment: I don't know why, but it can now!
use npm install <package-name> it work~

Comment: Yes, although the question remains, but the program can run!